# What's the technique of putting ellipsis to show hesitation in a lyrics called?

Tags: technique, lyrics

> You saw me the day before
>
> It all ended, and yet you've
>
> left me without words
>
> **I wish...**
>
> That you could let it go
>
> Let the past go, be free
>
> Free like the wind
>
> Free like the birds

Is the act of putting an ellipsis like that at the end of a verse to make the song more harmonic, is that a technique? Is there a name for it. Are there any popular example? Or is it something else than a technique? If so, is it done often? And could you find some examples in popular songs?

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment but this response isn't quite an answer.)

Can you elaborate more on what your end product should be? Do you have a character talking about writing music, either to another musician or to a non-musician? Music has its own language of components, but unless you're actually including a stave lines in your writing, you may want to stick with English to describe music rather than musical terminology. Many people who do not read music may be frustrated or discouraged by suddenly seeing music in the middle of a story. Of course, maybe you are writing non-fiction about a composer....

If you wish to stick with music, the term "caesura" may be one option. [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesura)
(Used to give musicians in need an air a moment to get some, or to indicate a longer pause at the director's artistic judgement). Additionally, there is a music stack exchange that you may wish to peruse.